# Angular 5: How to handle subscriptions for both async and subscribe

Tags: angular, observable, angular-observable

I have a situation where I get a list of some items and I use `async` in template. However, for whatever reason, I need to get the first item in component - I need to work a lot with that first element, so I can't just get the first item in template. So, I also subscribe to the same observable. Is this "allowed"? Am I doing any memory leaks this way? Here's an basic example of what I mean (a live example http://plnkr.co/edit/tulvIgxBjpOoUZ4Gk3hI?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>First item: {{first?.first_name}}</h2>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
          {{ item.first_name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  items$: Observable<any>;
  _subscribe: Subscription;
  first: any;

  constructor(private api: RestAPI) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.api.getItems();
    this._subscribe = this.items$.subscribe((items) => {
      this.first = items[0];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: live example http://plnkr.co/edit/tulvIgxBjpOoUZ4Gk3hI?p=preview

Comment: If you don't unsubscribe `this.items$` subscription inside component(`ngOnDestroy` event), then it could cause memory leak, otherwise `| async` takes care of auto unsubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. So immediately I do `.subscribe` I need to unsubscribe in `OnDestroy`? I even think that it's not even possible (there's no `unsubscribe` method for `item$`, since it's not subscrption).

Comment: @uglycode you can create in your service method that only return first item and then use async. Or you can subscribe in your component and create subscription and on ngDestroy unsubscribe.

Comment: you can use a do if you want to do some with the Observable:  this.items$ = this.api.getItems().do((result)=>{console.log(result);this.first=result[0]})

Comment: Thanks guys, I provided a live example with `unsubscribe`, can you please check it and tell me if that's how you meant? Also @Eliseo, can you update my example with your advice?

Comment: have you tried `first` operator?

Comment: No, but I guess I'd still have to unsubscribe? I need both the complete array and the first item.

Comment: Using `first` or `take(1)` does not require an `unsubscribe`. Both methods causes the observable to emit only one value and then to call the `complete` callback. See https://plnkr.co/edit/ckvC2tRKCxCay5vsqXwI?p=preview

Comment: I found an interesting solution: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services